# How can I open a TCP Connection and send data over another Method in WPF?

Tags: wpf, tcp

I want to Connect my WPF Application to a Raspberry Pi 3b. After some internet searching I decided to go with TCP. In the current state, I send a string and close the connection immediately. But I want the server, running on the Raspi, to send me data back at any time, which doesn't work when the Socket is Down.
How can I Open a Socket and access it in an other Method?

I've tried:

```
namespace WpfApp2
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private TcpClient tcp;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void _Write(string message)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = tcp.GetStream();
        Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);


    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            tcp = new TcpClient(ip_box.Text,Convert.ToInt32(port_box.Text));
            Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hallo");
            NetworkStream stream = tcp.GetStream();

            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");

        }

    }
```

Here is the Python Code:

```python
print"Pi is starting..."
import socket
print"Socket importet..."
import time
print"Time importet..."
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
print"GPIO importet..."
import sys
import thread
print"-----------"



ip = "192.168.178.120"
port = 5335

print"Ip: "+ip
print"Port: "+str(port)


axis_1_to_deg=22
axis_2_to_deg=111

def moveaxis1(a):

         x=0
         mvstp1=int(a)
         if(mvstp1<0):
             GPIO.output(stepper1_dir,GPIO.HIGH)
             mvstp1=int(mvstp1)* -1
         elif(mvstp1>0):
            GPIO.output(stepper1_dir,GPIO.LOW)
         while x<int(mvstp1):
             GPIO.output(stepper1_step,GPIO.LOW)
             GPIO.output(stepper1_step,GPIO.HIGH)
             x=x+1
             time.sleep(0.002)

def moveaxis2(a):

         x=0
         mvstp2=int(a)
         if(mvstp2<0):
             GPIO.output(stepper2_dir,GPIO.HIGH)
             mvstp2=int(mvstp2)* -1
         elif(mvstp2>0):
            GPIO.output(stepper2_dir,GPIO.LOW)
         while x<int(mvstp2):
             GPIO.output(stepper2_step,GPIO.LOW)
             GPIO.output(stepper2_step,GPIO.HIGH)
             x=x+1
             time.sleep(0.00005)


def moveaxis3(a):

         x=0
         mvstp3=int(a)
         if(mvstp3<0):
             GPIO.output(stepper3_dir,GPIO.HIGH)
             mvstp3=int(mvstp3)* -1
         elif(mvstp3>0):
            GPIO.output(stepper3_dir,GPIO.LOW)
         while x<int(mvstp3):
             GPIO.output(stepper3_step,GPIO.LOW)
             GPIO.output(stepper3_step,GPIO.HIGH)
             x=x+1
             time.sleep(0.00005)

print"Thread 3 Declared"
print"Threads Declared"

x=0
stepper1_step=40
stepper2_step=36
stepper3_step=26

stepper1_dir=38
stepper2_dir=32
stepper3_dir=24
calib_1=8
calib_2=10

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(calib_1,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(calib_2,GPIO.IN)

GPIO.setup(stepper1_step,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(stepper1_dir,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(stepper2_step,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(stepper2_dir,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(stepper3_step,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(stepper3_dir,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

pos_axis1 = 0
pos_axis2 = 0
pos_axis3 = 0




print " "


    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((ip, port))
    sock.listen(1)




    print("RasPI Server up / awaiting connection...")       

    while True:
       print"------------"
        connection,client_addres =sock.accept()    # buffer size is 1024 bytes

     data = connection.recv(1024)
    print "Received message:", data
    if(data.startswith( 'stp')):
         print "Commands for Steppers are being proccesed"
         stp,move_stp1,move_stp2,move_stp3 = data.split(',')
         print("Steps Axis 1"+move_stp1)
         print("Steps Axis 2"+move_stp2)
         print("Steps Axis 3"+move_stp3)
         print"------------"
         print"Threads are starting..."
         in_pos_1=int(move_stp1)*axis_1_to_deg
         in_pos_2=int(move_stp2)*axis_2_to_deg
         in_pos_3=int(move_stp3)*axis_2_to_deg

         z1 = pos_axis1 - in_pos_1
         z2 = pos_axis2 - in_pos_2
         z3 = pos_axis3 - in_pos_3

         thread.start_new_thread(moveaxis1,(z1,))
         thread.start_new_thread(moveaxis2,(z2,))
         thread.start_new_thread(moveaxis3,(z3,))

         pos_axis1 = in_pos_1
         pos_axis2 = in_pos_2
         pos_axis3 = in_pos_3

         print"Position 1: " +str(pos_axis1)
         print"Position 2: " +str(pos_axis2)
         print"Position 3: " +str(pos_axis3)
    elif(data =="calib"):
        ready = False
        while ready==False:
            if(GPIO.input(calib_1)==True):
                moveaxis1(1)
            else:
                ready=True
                moveaxis1(-40*axis_1_to_deg)
        ready = False
        while ready==False:
            if(GPIO.input(calib_2)==True):
                moveaxis2(1)
            else:
                ready=True
                moveaxis2(-85*axis_2_to_deg)

    elif(data=="set_0"):
        pos_axis1=0
        pos_axis2=0
        pos_axis3=0

    elif(data=="exit"):
        break
    print" "



GPIO.cleanup()
sock.close()
print"Fertig"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a console application in Raspberry using Net Core, you need to install Net core runtime in your raspberry, (You should not install net core sdk in your raspberry) then you can compile  your "console service" application using dot net.

```
dotnet publish -r linux-arm
```

Here reference
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md

Your console application should have a infinite while using TCPListener class to take multiples connection if you lost any connection.
Here some examples:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx

Also you should to know about "Reverse Connection" If your raspberry there is behinde a router and your client application in another network, but in a local network you should not have problems.

Another way, is to use "Azure IOT Hub" to control raspberry from any place https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/iot-hub/ (but I dont prefer this way, because have a cost)

Comment: I dont think u understood my question right. I wnat to communicate TO the RasPi over TCP. The Raspberry part isnt the problem, the windows/pc part is it.

Comment: Ofc, gonna post it

Comment: I think the problem is in the server, server is closing your client connection.

Comment: Another thing you should send a dummy message to server to prevent lost connection for time out, or you need to retry open a new connection if lost it

Comment: Your server just receive the message once, then It keep waiting for new clients in accept method, you could add a while to receive multiples messages while connection is alive, If you lost connection you can call accept again, In other side you should use threads to manage client connections from server.